# JPA Mapping OneToMany with partial embedded id child

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mapping

Simple example (hopefully). I have a primary key (using a sequence) in one table and that value is a partial FK into a child table. I see the Parent is trying to be saved with a generated sequence, but then I see an exception that the parentId in the embeddable is null while saving the child. The sequence value used for the parent is not being carried over to the child. I have tried many annotations and mappedBy/join column names but no luck.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

```java
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "audit_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "audit_seq", allocationSize = 5)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<>();

   //Used to add child record o the parent
    public void addChild(Child child) {
        this.childList .add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class ChildId {
   private Long parentId;
   private String name;
}

public class Child {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildId id;

    private String myCol;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved with the use of a couple of annotations:

Parent class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent",  orphanRemoval = true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Child class:

```
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("id")
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Parent parent;
```

Now all objects are being persisted when saving the parent with the appropiate sequence id.